# Error: keras merge LSTM layers in sum mode

Tags: keras, lstm

I would like to merge two sequential models in sum mode into one model using Keras as:

```
left = Sequential()
left.add(LSTM(64,activation='sigmoid',stateful=True,batch_input_shape=(10,look_back,dim)))
right = Sequential()
right.add(LSTM(64,activation='sigmoid',stateful=True,batch_input_shape=(10,look_back,dim)))
model = Sequential()
model.add(Add()([left, right]))
```

But the statement `model.add(Add()[left,right])` gives the error:

```
Layer add was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received 
type: <class 'keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'>. Full input:
[<keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x7fac9c0f36a0>, 
<keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x7fac9c0f3748>]. 
All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says what's the problem: the method expects a Tensors, but you are giving a Sequential model object.

Use functional model (`from keras.models import Model`), not Sequential.

Then, merge the models with:

```
merged_models = Model(inputs=[first_model_input, second_model_input], outputs=[first_model_output, second_model_output])
```

or whatever your input looks like.

Comment: In my case, I need to pass the output of Add() to next layers after merging. For example Dense. If I use: merged_models = Model(inputs=[left.input, right.input], outputs=[left.output,right.output])
dd=Dense(dm, activation='linear')(merged_models.output)
 It again gives error that dense was expecting one input but it got two. Does this mean that the output of Model is not merging them

Comment: Then your approach (and the question) is wrong.

Just don't create the models while you are not finished with defining all the layers. That way you won't get errors about expecting the Tensors, but something else was given. And then create the model at the end.

Comment: `Does this mean that the output of Model is not merging them `
Yes, the model is not merging the outputs, that's not the purpose of Functional model constructor. To merge the layers, use layers, not model constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I created a similar model with the functional api:

```
leftInput = keras.layers.Input((10, 10))
left = keras.layers.LSTM(64, activation='sigmoid')(leftInput)
rightInput = keras.layers.Input((10, 10))
right = keras.layers.LSTM(64, activation='sigmoid')(rightInput)
output = keras.layers.Add()([left, right])
model = keras.Model(inputs=[leftInput, rightInput], outputs=output)
```

I don't know the specifics of your model but this should also work for your problem.